# Calculators for four weight training programs in JSP: need some guidance

Tags: java, jsp

So, for a Uni project (UI programming), I'm writing a webpage with calculators for four separate strength training programs, all of which require separate calculations to produce a program. I'm fairly new to programming, and have never used JSP before. In fact, it was just today that I started doing the JSP tutorials in NetBeans.

I'm kind of at a loss here, not really sure how to go about doing this, so I'll start by outlining the way the training programs are supposed to work (I know this is a bit long-winded, but I figure I might as well put as much info in here as possible).

In all programs, the imaginary lifter inputs their best lifts, and the program then constructs a training routine for them.

One program is a linear progression, that just adds weight either 2kg or 5kg at a time for 12 weeks (Squat and DL 5kg, bench and OHP 2kg).

One follows the same basic principle, but with different lifts.

One is based on a popular training program known as 531. The program is constructed of 4 week mini cycles in which the weights go up over the course of four weeks. This is % based (as in week 1 would be 75% of the weight that the user had entered into the form, nest week is 85% etc.).

The last is a more complex olympic lifting program with various different percentages used. The user can choose between having a 3 day or 6 day a week program. The 3 day program is the same, but without the extra days (by which I mean the 3 day program uses three days that are the same as the six day variant).

Below is my java class (at this point). Since the programs utilize many of the same lifts, I thought it would save time to just have all of the lifts in the same source, and have the separate programs call them if they needed them. However, now that I've been thinking, since the programs require different calculations, maybe I should actually have different source files for all of the separate training programs?

The way it is currently set up is that the source file (below) just houses the variables, and my intention was to have separate HTML pages for each training routine, that contain forms into which the user inputs their data, which when prompted, moves the user to a JSP which shows them the result (i.e. their program).

```
package org.packageLifts.Lifts;

public class Lifts {
private int Squat;
private int Bench;
private int Deadlift;
private int OHP;
private int Snatch;
private int CleanJerk;
private int FrontSquat;

public Lifts() {

Squat = 0;
Bench = 0;
Deadlift = 0;
OHP = 0;                        /* Init all maxes to 0*/
Snatch = 0;
CleanJerk = 0;
FrontSquat = 0;



}

/**
 * @return the Squat
 */
public int getSquat() {
    return Squat;
}

/**
 * @param Squat the Squat to set
 */
public void setSquat(int Squat) {
    this.Squat = Squat;
}

/**
 * @return the Bench
 */
public int getBench() {
    return Bench;
}

/**
 * @param Bench the Bench to set
 */
public void setBench(int Bench) {
    this.Bench = Bench;
}

/**
 * @return the Deadlift
 */
public int getDeadlift() {
    return Deadlift;
}

/**
 * @param Deadlift the Deadlift to set
 */
public void setDeadlift(int Deadlift) {
    this.Deadlift = Deadlift;
}

/**
 * @return the OHP
 */
public int getOHP() {
    return OHP;
}

/**
 * @param OHP the OHP to set
 */
public void setOHP(int OHP) {
    this.OHP = OHP;
}

/**
 * @return the Snatch
 */
public int getSnatch() {
    return Snatch;
}

/**
 * @param Snatch the Snatch to set
 */
public void setSnatch(int Snatch) {
    this.Snatch = Snatch;
}

/**
 * @return the CleanJerk
 */
public int getCleanJerk() {
    return CleanJerk;
}

/**
 * @param CleanJerk the CleanJerk to set
 */
public void setCleanJerk(int CleanJerk) {
    this.CleanJerk = CleanJerk;
}

/**
 * @return the FrontSquat
 */
public int getFrontSquat() {
    return FrontSquat;
}

/**
 * @param FrontSquat the FrontSquat to set
 */
public void setFrontSquat(int FrontSquat) {
    this.FrontSquat = FrontSquat;
}



}
```

As I said, I am very much new to how this all works. My main questions are:

1. Should the actual calculations take place in the source file? If so, I would assume that all training programs should have their own sources. Am I right?
2. Taking the 531 program as an example, how would one go about printing four weeks of training routine with the weights being 75%, 85%, 95% and 50% of the input given, respectively?

Sorry for the excruciatingly long question. Any and all help is appreciated, in addition to my main questions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is just an observation but I would not capitalize your class fields. Use mixed case instead. Usually in Java we reserve capital variable names for a `Class` name. So you can leave `Lifts` but I would change your class fields to mixed case like: `squat`, `someOtherVariable`, `mixedCase`, `cleanJerk`, etc.

Comment: What @gonzo is talking about: [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll do that.